# How can I checkout several private Github repos using Jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins

I have a small problem with Jenkins and private Github repos.
To check out a private repo, one usually needs one of two things:

- the private SSH key of a user on that repo
- the private SSH key of a registered "deployment key" for that repo

The deployment key was made for this kind of interaction. The problem is that deployment keys have to be unique across projects, so I'd have to use a different key every time.
This means that I'd have to add another key to the ssh-agent for the Jenkins user for every additional repo.
This also means that by default, the agent would try all of the available keys and would probably get the connection dropped after a few bad attempts with a wrong key.

The Jenkins git plugin doesn't seem to allow pointing it at an SSH key.
Jenkins doesn't allow any commandline interaction before the checkout, so I can't use any bash tricks to set the correct key.

So far the only solution seems to be:

1. Create an "my_jenkins_account" user in github
2. Add a public key to the user
3. Add the account to repos that I'd want to check out using Jenkins
4. Add the user's private key to the jenkins user

Any alternative suggestions?

Answer (score 13):

This isn't exactly an answer, just an echo in the dark to let you know that I do pretty much the same thing.

1. Run Jenkins as a user called `jenkins`
2. `sudo` as this user and create a public ssh key
3. Create a free GitHub account called `myorg-machines`
4. Add this `jenkins` user's public ssh key to the `myorg-machines` account keys on GitHub. I name this key `jenkins on server.name.com` to keep things organized.
5. Create a GitHub team called `Machines - Pull only`. Add the `myorg-machines` GitHub user to that team, and give that team pull access to my appropriate private repos.

I agree it seems klunky, but it's actually been pretty easy to manage over a year or so now.

Comment: Thanks, we're running this setup now too. It works, but it still feels wrong :(

Comment: Well in a way, the jenking server _acts_ as additional user for your repositories. It is, in a manner of speaking, a separate entity acting on the repositories. It is not completely unreasonable to map this entity to a github user. (Having said that, it is still a bit klinky, as has been said. But got to do, what we go to to ...)